# Renaming files and directories with the same pattern in R

Tags: r, directory, rename, file-rename

I am trying to rename a number of files and folders with a new name.

Example old name: `corrected_original_wh_ah108090.pdf`

Example new name: `corrected_original_gsmp01358_108090.pdf`

Example old path: `Data/Test2/ARGOS/wh_ah108090/crawl/corrected_original_wh_ah108090.pdf`

Example new path:`Data/Test2/ARGOS/gsmp01358_108090/crawl/corrected_original_gsmp01358_108090.pdf`

Example metadata:

```
old         new
wh_ah108090 gsmp01358_108090
wh_ah108091 gsmp01359_108091
wh_ah108092 gsmp01360_108092
wh_ah108093 gsmp01361_108093
wh_ah108096 gsmp01362_108096
wh_ah108102 gsmp01363_108102
wh_ah108106 gsmp01364_108106
```

Code:

```
# Read metadata for ID's #
meta <- read.csv('Metadata.csv')


# list all file paths
pathLs <- list.files('Data/Test2/', recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)


# select only files with old format on the list (for full dataset where some files already have new name)
tbl<- pathLs [!grepl("gsmp", pathLs )]

# select only files with old format on metadata
metadata<- meta[!meta$old =="",]

# function to change old names for new
fileList <- apply(metadata,1, 
                 function(x) {
                 fnam <- x['old']
                 fnam <- as.character(unlist(fnam))


                 newnam <- gsub(fnam, as.character(unlist(x['new'])), tbl[grepl(fnam, tbl)])
                 return(newnam)})

# Create dataframe with old and new names

to <- as.character(unlist(fileList))
from <- tbl 

# Use rename 
file.rename(from, to)
```

For some reason this file rename doesn't work.
Is this because I cannot rename files and directories in a path at the same time?

Comment: In your metadata, how do you come up with the `01358` in `wh_ah108090 gsmp01358_108090`?

Comment: Hi @r2evans , thanks for your reply. `gsmp01358` is a unique ID that will be used once these files are added to a larger database with thousands of files and directories. `wh_ah108090` is an old ID that I want to change to this new format. In this example the `01358` could be anything (I assume) and the process will still be the same regardless of the new name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No loops required.

```r
metadata <- read.table(header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, text="
old         new
wh_ah108090 gsmp01358_108090
wh_ah108091 gsmp01359_108091
wh_ah108092 gsmp01360_108092
wh_ah108093 gsmp01361_108093
wh_ah108096 gsmp01362_108096
wh_ah108102 gsmp01363_108102
wh_ah108106 gsmp01364_108106")
metadata$new2 <- sprintf("gsmp%05d_%s",
                         1357L + seq_len(nrow(metadata)), # 1357 can be anything?
                         gsub("\\D", "", metadata$old))
metadata
#           old              new             new2
# 1 wh_ah108090 gsmp01358_108090 gsmp01358_108090
# 2 wh_ah108091 gsmp01359_108091 gsmp01359_108091
# 3 wh_ah108092 gsmp01360_108092 gsmp01360_108092
# 4 wh_ah108093 gsmp01361_108093 gsmp01361_108093
# 5 wh_ah108096 gsmp01362_108096 gsmp01362_108096
# 6 wh_ah108102 gsmp01363_108102 gsmp01363_108102
# 7 wh_ah108106 gsmp01364_108106 gsmp01364_108106

file.rename(metadata$old, metadata$new2) # should do it
```

Comment: Ok I am trying to undersand what you have done here. You have created a new column. But what is the step to actually rename the file itself? Does the sprintf rename? This is a subset of data by the way. I have over 14,000 files I need to apply this rename to. Each with a corresponding new name that is not always consecutive..

Comment: I updated the answer to include the one-line for actual renaming. I might be missing some of what you need, my apologies. The only reason I added a column was for a side-by-side comparison with your `$new`, it is otherwise not necessary. Frankly, a `data.frame` is not necessary, two vectors would work just as well.

Comment: I'm inferring from the code inside your `for` loop that there is more that needs to be considered here, including files that *shouldn't* be renamed. Much of that might be handled in the `list.files` call to get the filenames, or it can be handled in a filter after that. It could be much simpler (for me) if you provided the output from `dput(head(pathLs,10))`, assuming that that provides at least one each of "yes, rename" and "no, do not rename".

Comment: Hi, the problem seems to be in the rename. The rest of the code gets me what I want in terms of the `from` and `to`. (This piece of code removes those files that I do not want to rename: `tbl<- pathLs [!grepl("gsmp", pathLs` ). So I am happy with that. I am just unsure about why it reads `FALSE` when I try the rename itself.

Comment: Since `file.rename` returns a *"logical vector indicating which operation succeeded for each of the files attempted"*, the `FALSE` could be due to several things, including: (1) one or more of "old" are locked; (2) one or more of "new" exist and cannot be over-written; (3) one or more of "new" contain non-standard and/or disallowed characters. If one of those three, there is very little I can do to help troubleshoot. If you know which of the files cannot be renamed (it is a vector, after all), perhaps you can hunt down the failing file(s).

Comment: I figured it out with the addition of:

`#create folders to hold files (both folders and files with final name) sapply(unique(paste0(dirname(to))), dir.create, recursive = TRUE) #files with final names apply(compare, 1, function(x) file.rename(from = x['from'], to = x['to'])) #remove empty folders with older names library(icesTAF) rmdir(paste0(unique(dirname(from))), recursive = TRUE)`

Comment: I'm glad you found an answer. Is there a reason you chose an external package for `icesTAF::rmdir` instead of using `unlink(..., recursive=TRUE)` (which removes directories)?

Answer (score 0):

`list.files` does not list any directory name, so your code renames only the files, but not the directories. So, theoretically your code should work. Specifically, which part of the code is not working?

Comment: I know this is not an answer but since my reputation is not enough to make comments, I posted this as answer.

Comment: I do have a directory attached, sorry first line should read `setwd()` and the `list.files` takes all the files from the additional folders in `Data/Test2/`. With `recursive = TRUE` I thought it listed directories. The problem I get is when I use the `file.rename(from, to)` it gives me `FALSE` for all files.

Comment: `recursive = TRUE` makes it list all files in all sub directories. It still list only files though. For listing directories; you can use `list.dirs` function. 
About the error, it seems you are in the wrong directory. Could you use `setwd()` with directory just before `Data/Test2/`  and try again?

Comment: Ok, so I used `basename(tbl)` to access only the files as I see `file.rename` doesn't rename directories. So for now if we forget the directories, how should I write `file.rename()` to include all the files in `from`? `file.rename(from, to)` doesn't work and nor does `file.rename(from == paste0(tbl, from), to == paste0(tbl, to))`. Am i missing something in this command?

Comment: Have you set the working directory as I said? Could you write the output of `getwd() `?

Comment: What I mean is that, let's say your files are in `Desktop/Data/Test2/`,  in order to run your original code, your working directory should be set in `Desktop`,  not `Desktop/Data/Test2/`.

Comment: Oh right, I see what you are asking, yes it has been set as that all along as my metadata is in the previous directory.

Comment: Could the error be in permissions related to file renaming?

Comment: It could be that, but I suspect the problem is about the file path/full names. Could you provide me output of `head(from)` and `head(to)`?

Comment: `> head(from)
[1] "corrected_original_wh_ah108090.pdf" "original_wh_ah108090.pdf"           "wh_ah108090_argos_k_corr.csv"      
[4] "wh_ah108090_k_daily_gap.csv"        "wh_ah108090_k_daily_gap.pdf"        "wh_ah108090_k_daily_gaps_merge.pdf" `



                  `> head(to)
[1] "corrected_original_gsmp01358_108090.pdf" "original_gsmp01358_108090.pdf"           "gsmp01358_108090_argos_k_corr.csv"      
[4] "gsmp01358_108090_k_daily_gap.csv"        "gsmp01358_108090_k_daily_gap.pdf"        "gsmp01358_108090_k_daily_gaps_merge.pdf" `

Comment: This is strange. There should have been `Data/Test2/` before each items. If your working directory is not set in as `Data/Test2/`, it will have trouble finding these files. In this case, please set your working directory to the directory containing all these files, which is I assume `Data/Test2/`.
I have tried your code and everything worked fine. So if directory is not a problem It should be about permissions.

Comment: I managed to figure it out with that addition of this code:

`#create folders to hold files (both folders and files with final name)
sapply(unique(paste0(dirname(to))), dir.create, recursive = TRUE)

#files with final names
apply(compare, 1, function(x) file.rename(from = x['from'], to = x['to']))


#remove empty folders with older names
library(icesTAF)
rmdir(paste0(unique(dirname(from))), recursive = TRUE)`

Comment: I am glad you've figured it out.